# What would be the functional way of getting the mean of each vector in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I am a beginner to functional programming and Clojure programming language and I'm resorting to `recur` pretty much for everything. I have a dataset in csv, imported as a map. I have extracted the info I need to use as vectors. Each column is a vector `[1 5 10 8 3 2 1 ...]` and I want to calculate the mean of each column. I wrote the following function:

```
(defn mean
  "Calculate the mean for each column"
  ([columns]
   (mean columns []))
  ([columns
    means]
   (if (empty? columns)
     means
     (recur (rest columns)
            (conj means (float (/ (reduce + (first columns)) (count (first columns)))))))))

;; Calcule the mean for the following vectors
(mean [[1 2 3] [1 2 3] [1 2 3]])
; => [2.0 2.0 2.0]
```

Is this a functional way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd break it down a little farther and use `map` instead of `for`. I personally like having many, smaller functions:

```
(defn mean [row]
  (/ (apply + row) (count row)))

(defn mean-rows [rows]
  (map mean rows))
```

But this is the same general idea as @Alan's answer.

The way you're doing it is already considered "functional". It should be said though that while using `recur` is good, usually you can achieve what you need more easily using `reduce`, or at least `map`. These options eliminate the need for explicit recursion, and generally lead to simpler, easier to understand code.

Comment: Is there any difference between `reduce` and `apply` in this situation?

Comment: @VascoFerreira No. They do the same thing. If you look at the overloads of `+`, you'll see that it accepts a var-args overload. The var-arg overload is basically a reduction over `+`.

Comment: IMHO the key point for "make this more functional": it's always a good idea to develop/extract the most useful function (`mean` in this case) and if you really need it alot, give the `(map f seq)` a name (like `mean-rows`) - but at that point it's just a triviality.

Comment: @cfrick I too thought that "smallest functional component" was a FP principle, I can't find any good references stating that it is in fact associated with FP. I think it's a good practice in general though, and one that I almost take too far sometimes. I wanted to add a reference link along with a little blurb, but I can't find any good sources.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple answer:

```
(defn mean
  "Calculate the mean of each column"
  [cols]
  (vec    ; this is optional if you don't want it
    (for [col cols]
      (/                      ; ratio of num/denom
        (reduce + col)        ; calculates the numerator
        (count col)))))       ; the number of items

(mean [[1 2 3] [1 2 3] [1 2 3]]) => [2 2 2]
```

If you haven't seen it yet, you can get started here:  https://www.braveclojure.com/

I recommend buying the printed version of the book, as it has more than the online version.